# List of binary compatible Linux derivates

Tags: linux

I'm looking for an overview of **binary compatible** linux derivates to enterprise Linux versions.
A usable [definition of this compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code_compatibility) is given on Wikipedia.

I already know candidates for this:

- [CentOS (Community ENTerprise
  Operating System)](http://www.centos.org) is binary
  compatible to [RHEL (Red Hat
  Enterprise Linux)](http://www.redhat.com/rhel/).
- [SL (Scientific Linux)](http://www.scientificlinux.org) is binary
  compatible to RHEL (Red Hat
  Enterprise Linux).

I think there are for sure many more. Who can help? Maybe this will grow into a fine overview... I'd like to edit the question to complete it with the data from answers.

Comment: well, any software, assuming the distros use the same versions of libraries (notably libc/glibc), and on the same architecture should be binary compatable - i could compile a staticly compiled software on say, debian, and there's a good chance it'll run on RHEL. Packages on the other hand do not translate well.

Comment: @Journeyman is as close as you're going to get to an answer. Do you mean that their *package management systems are compatable*?

Comment: @peth Thanks you for your hint - do you think, this question might fit better in `server fault`?

Answer (score 2):

Lets see if i can answer this, without answering this.

Now, every OS has two sets of interfaces for a program to talk to the OS - the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), or Application Binary Interface and the API, the [Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) -in this case, the more interesting part is the ABI

All modern linux based OSes have the same ABI - the [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) - any linux distribution that supports the LSB should be able to run the same software - as such all modern linux distributions are, in theory binary compatable, though there's some issues.

On the other hand, if you're talking about *package* compatability, its a whole different kettle of fish. Centos and Scientific linux ARE RHEL with the copyrighted art bits removed. There's also debian -> ubuntu -> mint , where you shouldn't mix repos but you can borrow packages at a pinch.

Its pretty much a university thesis worth of information.